# Why does this template variable lead to a compiler warning?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, compiler-warnings, c++14

Why am I getting this warning from Clang? This seems like a sensible use of a templated constant to me.

`warning: variable 'M_PI<int>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]`

```c++
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr T M_PI = T(3.1415926535897932);

template <typename T>
constexpr T CalcCircumference(T d)
{
    return d * M_PI<T>;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << CalcCircumference(42.0f);
}
```

Edit: Apparently a minimalistic test case is confusing to some. I have embellished it a bit to hopefully alleviate that.

Comment: @hvd This code is returning a constant value from main, so of *course* it's pointless, but made less pointless by the fact that it seems simple enough and yet it generates a warning and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just ignore the warning, and should avoid variable templates altogether for now.

Consider

```
template <typename T> T var = 0;
int main() { return var<int>; }
```

This compiles without warnings, links, and runs to return zero.

```
template <typename T> T var = 0;
template <typename T> T func() { return var<T>; }
int main() { return func<int>(); }
```

This compiles without warnings, but does not link: it gives an error message.

```
$ clang++ test2.cc -o test2 -std=c++1y -pedantic -Wall
/tmp/test2-736968.o:test2.cc:function int func(): error: undefined reference to 'var'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Forcing an explicit instantiation does work:

```
template <typename T> T var = 0;
template int var<int>;
template <typename T> T func() { return var<T>; }
int main() { return func<int>(); }
```

I'd say this shows that the implementation of variable templates in clang is incomplete. Your use of `constexpr` merely makes it so that clang detects its own incomplete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug (filed as [PR19305](http://llvm.org/PR19305)) in earlier versions of Clang. See also [PR19571](http://llvm.org/PR19571) and [PR17846](http://llvm.org/PR17846), which were different bugs with similar symptoms. These are all fixed in Clang 3.5.